# Gradient does not cover full text

Tags: html, css, text, gradient, css-gradients

I have made a gradient text using this method       ;

```
.warn
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(153,0,0,1) 17%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 100%);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

But when I look at the gradient on the page, it is like this: [image: Gradient in text not complete]

Does anyone know why this happens? Thanks.

P.S. The text is italic and uses Ubuntu Italic font.

Comment: add some padding-right

Comment: Could you put up a snippet which shows the problem as I haven't been able to reproduce the linear gradient giving that sharp cutoff so maybe need to see it with the typeface.

Comment: @AHaworth What do you mean? The code, or the final result?